# Prove that $\lim_{x \to -1^-}\frac{5}{(x+1)^3} = -\infty $ using the $\delta M$ definition of infinite limits

Tags: calculus, limits

I am posting this for you guys to let me know whether it's wrong and/or give me any advice regarding the proof.

Thank you.

Given $ M < 0 $ we need $\delta > 0$ such that $  -1 -\delta< x < -1 \Rightarrow \frac{5}{(x+1)^3} < M$

Now  $ -1 -\delta< x < -1 \Leftrightarrow  -\delta < x + 1 < 0$

Now $ \frac{5}{(x+1)^3} < M \Leftrightarrow x + 1 > \sqrt[3]{\frac{5}{M}} $

So take $\delta = -\sqrt[3]{\frac{5}{M}}$

Then  $-1 -\delta< x < -1 \Leftrightarrow -1 - (-\sqrt[3]{\frac{5}{M}})< x < -1 \Rightarrow  \frac{5}{(x+1)^3} < M$

So  $\lim_{x \to -1^-}\frac{5}{(x+1)^3} = -\infty $

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: Your choice of $\delta$ is fine. If you are going to write the proof in this style, that is, finding $\delta$ in the body of the proof, then you should write your transformation steps as equivalences, i.e. with $\Leftrightarrow$. For example, $-1-\delta < x < -1 \Leftrightarrow -\delta < x < 0$. All your transformations are equivalences, so this is not a big deal.

Comment: @Ian That makes sense to me, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The proof now starts out correctly.  There are still issues. 
For example, the line

$ \frac{5}{(x+1)^3} < M \Rightarrow$$x + 1 > \sqrt[3]{\frac{5}{M}}$

though correct, has the implication running in the wrong direction. We want to show that if $\delta$ is chosen appropriately, then $\frac{5}{(1+x)^3}$ is $\lt M$. That is not the same thing as showing that if $\frac{5}{(1+x)^3}\lt M$ then $\dots$.

**Obsoleted answer below:**

The argument starts out incorrectly. You need to show that **for any** $M$ there exists a $\delta$ such that $\dots$.

**Remark:** Your handling of inequalities indicates that you can undoubtedly modify things to give a correct proof. But if the solution as it stands were being graded, it is likely that the grader would look at the first line, put an X through it, and go on to the next question.

Comment: Okay, I understand the mistake regarding "You need to show that for any M there exists a δ such that …". However I do not understand what you mean by "Your handling of inequalities indicates that you can undoubtedly modify things to give a correct proof", I can not deduce any information regarding that sentence other than that I am wrong.

Comment: I mean that you can undoubtedly show that for every $M$ there exists $\dots$.  Indeed you have shown it. The inequalities needed are the ones you wrote down.

Comment: I edited the first line. So would you now say that it would be graded as being correct?

Comment: There are still problems, but at least the grader would read beyond the first line. The argument needs to be reorganized. As the argument reads, your implication arrows run the wrong way, except in the concluding sentence.

Comment: I have done some editing, have a look now and tell me what you think, please.

Comment: It is now correct. The use of the biconditional detracts a bit from the clarity of the logic, but there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Great, thank you for your time.

Comment: You are welcome. One of the main goals of a first "analysis" course is clarity of arguments.